# What's the correct way to declare a __block variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, syntax

Should I declare it as

(#1) `ClassName * __block variableName`

or

(#2) `__block ClassName * variableName`

?

I seen a lot of code uses format #2, Including Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html).

But recently I found Apple's "[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html)" says:

> You should decorate variables correctly. When using qualifiers in an object variable declaration, the correct format is:
>
> `ClassName * qualifier variableName;`
>
> for example:
>
> `MyClass * __weak myWeakReference;`
>
> Other variants are technically incorrect but are “forgiven” by the compiler. To understand the issue, see http://cdecl.org/.

So I'm confused, Which format should I use in the future?

Comment: I think the notes from Apple is already very clear. #2 is correct, but compiler allow you to use #1 (because everyone is using #1). It is like `const int *` and `int const *` in C/C++

Comment: @BryanChen do you have your numbers mixed up? Apple's docs say you can use #2 but say #1 is really the correct way, as he quoted in the post.

Comment: @DanZimm you are correct. unfortunately I can't edit it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially the same. I personally prefer placing `__block` at the beginning since it's *more important* than the variable's type.